# Not run XAMPP because the port is conflict with Skype (in MAC)

Tags: apache, xampp, port, skype

I started XAMPP and it not connect. I read in some pages that I need to uncheck the box "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections" but I have a MAC and I cant find this option in my Skype.